How do I manage pointers to dynamically allocated structs?
I am trying to make an interpreter in C++ as a way to learn. I have the various types of literals and expressions written as structs, which carry either direct values or pointers to other structs. I was thinking about how I can manage the memory that was allocated with each node.
I have created a dummy code to give an idea of the actual code (of parser), along with what I am currently doing to manage the heap allocations.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
  string something;
  virtual ~A() {};
};

struct B : A
{
  A *leftSomething;
  A *rightSomething;
  string str;
  B(string s, A *left, A *right)
  {
    something = "B";
    str = s;
    leftSomething = left;
    rightSomething = right;
  }
  ~B()
  {
    cout << "B destructor called" << endl;
    delete leftSomething;
    delete rightSomething;
    cout << "B destructor ended" << endl;
  }
};

struct C : A
{
  int value;
  C(int n)
  {
    something = "C";
    value = n;
    cout << "C constructed" << endl;
  }
  ~C()
  {
    cout << "C destructed" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A *left = new C(1); // In the actual code left and right are returned from a function and I won't have access to them directly
  A *right = new C(2);
  A *ptr = new B("str", left, right); // The only pointer that I have access to directly
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}

Is my approach correct? There are a lot of other derived structs in the actual code and I have used the same approach for all of them. Are there any memory leak issues in the current approach?
The main reason I am doubting whether I am correct or not is because at times I see random gibberish in the terminal at the start the output of my code.
Screenshot
Screenshot of the random gibberish mentioned above
There is no such problem in the smaller dummy code I created here.
Is this because of memory management issues or something else?
I am using VS Code with Code Runner extension.

std::shared_ptr is your friend and wants you to be happy. It will tide you over for a long time before you need to do an actual garbage collector implementation.

"Is this because of memory management issues or something else?" We can't tell because you didn't show the code that reproduces the problem. "Is my approach correct?" This code here is fine. But very bug-prone, because you didn't implement copy constructor and assignment operator (and optionally some others, see rule of three). But a better approach (unless you're practicing the use of new and delete) is to use standard containers and smart pointers (std::unique_ptr in this case), which already implement those correctly.

Also I suggest reading Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?, Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?.

The biggest problem with the code is that if you pass single A* to two different B then it will crash. It will even crash if you pass single A* to single B as both parameters. Because of double delete. Use smart pointers instead.

Also "I am trying to make an interpreter in C++ as a way to learn." is a rather painful way of learning any language, especially C++.

You should not be using raw pointers so much. Also your datastructure leaks too much detail on the public part. . @Botje std::shared_ptr is not always your friend (risk of cyclic dependencies).  in this case B owns "A" and thus should use std;:unique_ptr<A>.

@PepijnKramer Given the context I would say shared_ptr is the better bet, as I can see the interpreted code doing something along the lines of var x = some_c.leftSomething, which would invalidate the unique ownership. Using shared_ptr models the reference counting semantics of perl/ruby/python along with the well-known problems of reference cycles and the need to introduce weak references into the language. Smashing into those limitations head-first is part of learning to write interpreters.

leftSomething and rightSomething should have been private, B should have a constructor  B(std::string s, A& left, A& right), members A leftSomething; or maybe std::optional<A> ... too often I see people still use pointers (smart or otherwise) where they are not needed.


cons and set-car! have entered the chat. *


@HolyBlackCat If I could link the github repo, would be better? Also, yes I was trying to manually manage memory, mainly as a challenge to myself and learn from my mistakes. I'll try to read the documentation of the smart pointers and see if I can try to replicate it in my code. Lastly, I do know about bits/stdc++.h lib and the namespace part, and I have avoided it in the main code. Just used it in the dummy code to quickly give an example. Thank you still

Nope, nobody wants to download and debug a whole repo. You need to do your homework: start removing parts of the program until the leak disappears, then you'll know exactly where it happens (see [mcve]). Or maybe enabling the address sanitizer will help find the problem.

@freakish noted. Also I've been learning C++ since a while, just didn't make any big projects. Though, I do admit, an interpreter is a huge jump. But I am not complaining. It's making me learn a lot of new things and read about the implementation of a lot of library elements in good detail to learn about their behaviour. I'm following a YouTube tutorial that implements this in TypeScript so I have to figure out how to implement in C++

@HolyBlackCat okay, I'll do what I can. Thank you!
